# Expanding Vector List Each by List of Instances - Julia

Tags: julia, expand

I would like to expand a vector of values each by a vector containing the number of each instance. I have come up with the following code which does the job but it seems like this is a common use so I am probably missing something.

```
valuelist = ["a","b","d","z"]
numberofinstance = [3,5,1,11]

valuevector = String[]
for i in 1:length(numberofinstance) 
  append!(valuevector , repeat([valuelist[i]], numberofinstance[i])) 
end
```

Comment: I found the function in StatsBase.jl. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are fine with using a package (basically a stdlib), the function you are looking for is called `inverse_rle` in [StatsBase.jl](http://juliastats.github.io/StatsBase.jl/stable/misc.html):

```
julia> using StatsBase

julia> inverse_rle(valuelist, numberofinstance)
20-element Array{String,1}:
 "a"
 "a"
 "a"
 "b"
 "b"
 "b"
 "b"
 "b"
 "d"
 "z"
 "z"
 "z"
 "z"
 "z"
 "z"
 "z"
 "z"
 "z"
 "z"
 "z"

julia> @btime inverse_rle($valuelist, $numberofinstance);
  76.799 ns (1 allocation: 240 bytes)

julia> @btime yoursolution($valuelist, $numberofinstance);
  693.329 ns (13 allocations: 1.55 KiB)
```

If you want to avoid packages, you could, in principle, broadcast `repeat` or `^` (powering) like so,

`vcat(collect.(.^(valuelist, numberofinstance))...)`

but I'd argue that this is relatively hard to parse and also slower than `inverse_rle`,

```
julia> @btime yoursolution($valuelist, $numberofinstance);
  693.329 ns (13 allocations: 1.55 KiB)

julia> @btime vcat(collect.(.^($valuelist, $numberofinstance))...)
  472.615 ns (9 allocations: 800 bytes)
```

However, since Julia allows you to write fast loops you can easily define your own simple function. The following is **much faster** than your solution (as fast as the [implementation in `StatsBase`](https://github.com/JuliaStats/StatsBase.jl/blob/88b481809cf3a4b4e381be37f4372122c2d7c361/src/misc.jl#L60)):

```
function multiply(vs, ns)
   r = Vector{String}(undef, sum(ns))
   c = 1
   @inbounds for i in axes(ns, 1)
       for k in 1:ns[i]
           r[c] = vs[i]
           c += 1
       end
   end
   r
end
```

Benchmark:

```
julia> @btime yoursolution($valuelist, $numberofinstance);
  693.329 ns (13 allocations: 1.55 KiB)

julia> @btime multiply($valuelist, $numberofinstance);
  76.469 ns (1 allocation: 240 bytes)
```